# Django count manytomany relation shows wrong number

Tags: django

I currently have a queryset which aims to extract a list of used colors associated with products, and return response with a list of colors and the amount of of products they're attached to. The colors originate in its own model called ProductColor and is referenced through a ManyToMany relationship in the Product model.

In the example bellow there are 3 products which has these colors registered:

- Product 1: White
- Product 2: White, Red
- Product 3: White

Wished output should be something like:

```
[
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "Red",
        "count": 1
    },
]
```

However, the closest i get is:

```
[
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "Red",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

The queryset is structured like this:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
            category__parent__name__iexact=category,
            status='available'
        ).values('colors__name', count=Count('colors', distinct=True))
```

I've tried to add .distinct() at the end of the queryset, but then it returns:

```
[
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "Red",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I've also tried using an annotation through `.annotate(count=Count('colors'))`, but then it returns:

```
[
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 7
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "Red",
        "count": 3
    }

 ]
```

How can i make sure it displays the correct amount next to the correct color (White: 4, Red: 1)?

Comment: How is the annotated output different from your estimated output?

Comment: @Jonas I need to "merge" the values, as you see now, i have 3 instances of white, with each a count of 1, i would like 1 instance of white with the count of 3.

Comment: yes but this is what annotate outputs, isnt it?

Comment: The current queryset ouputs this: ‘[
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "Red",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "colors__name": "White",
        "count": 1
    }
]‘